# Angular kinetic energy of a planar pendulum - Is the force at the pivot responsible for all change in the angular momentum>

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Is this statement below true? I cannot visualise how the pivot can cause a 'Moment of Force' on the club and be responsible for changes in its angular momentum.

Consider a golf club fixed to a pivot - like a planar pendulum - about an axis through the grip end. Two forces act on the club: A contact force at the motionless pivot point and gravity at the translating center of mass. From a work-energy perspective gravity does all the work, and more specifically, all the work done by gravity is linear. Yet, that linear work manifests itself in both linear and rotational kinetic energy in the club. The force at the fixed pivot does no work on the club.
From an impulse-momentum perspective, the combined linear impulses of gravity and the force at the pivot equals the change in linear momentum, while the angular impulse – due to the moment of force from the force at the pivot – equals the change in angular momentum. To be explicit, from a work-energy perspective gravity is responsible for all change in angular kinetic energy of a pendulum, while from an impulse-momentum perspective, the force at the pivot is responsible for all change in angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

If only gravity is responsible for the motion, all work comes from it. It is the case of a pendulum.

But it is also possible that we want more speed at the translating mass than what is possible only by gravity. In this case the torque applied at the pivot is also responsible for the work.

In the case of pure gravity driven movement, the work done from the max. to the min. height equals the change of kinetic energy, that is equal to the loss of gravity potential energy: $E_g = mg\Delta h$.

If there is an additional torque at the pivot point: $E_a = \int T\omega dt$, where $\omega$ is the instantaneous angular velocity.

The total energy: $E = E_g + E_a$

We can think of a fan that lost all blades but one. Part of the energy for move it from up to down position comes from gravity.

Comment: Many thanks but what about the force at the pivot being responsible for all angular momentum? The scenario is only 2 forces , the mass of the club, a contact force at the pivot. I cannot understand how a contact force can cause an increase in angular momentum.

Comment: It is necessary a torque, not only a contact force to increase angular momentum. The hand grip, if well observed, has more than one single point of contact. So, it can be a source of torque.

Comment: So I'm assuming that statement in my original question must be wrong. I couldn't understand how a contact force at the pivot can cause a 'moment of force' (it didn't make any sense to me at all!).  That statement was written by a doctor of biomechanics so maybe his physics is flawed.

Comment: His article is here if anyone is interested. https://www.golfsciencejournal.org/article/12640-how-amateur-golfers-deliver-energy-to-the-driver

Comment: What about the reaction forces between the pivot and whatever stable platform (ie. a wall) it's attached to ?  Can the reaction forces be deemed to be providing an eccentric force across the COM of the club?

Comment: Attn: Claudio Saspinski -  I've found a pendulum animation showing the reaction forces required to keep the pivot restrained at the same location. They do seem to show eccentric forces across the COM of the club. Maybe these reaction forces can be deemed to be causing all the changes in the angular momentum. https://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum/reaction-pendulum-en.html

Comment: Regarding my comment above , I suspect any pivot reaction forces being the cause of all changes in angular momentum would have to be from the perspective of the COM (ie. the 'non-inertial frame of reference' being at the accelerating COM )

Comment: In the animation, if the horizontal and vertical components of the reaction forces are added, the resultant has always the direction pivot -> COM. So, the torque is zero. And torque is change of angular momentum with time.

Comment: Many thanks again .